# What is R.layout.search?

Tags: java, android, searchactivity

I'm creating a search widget and a searchable activity. I followed the android developer guide and have this so far.

Here is my `searchableActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
    }
}
```

As mentioned, R.layout.search is creating the error. I don't have a search xml in layouts, and I don't understand what I am supposed to define within search.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a layout named search.xml in your res/layout folder where you'll show the search results. 
I my case I showed the search results in a RecyclerView and here's a sample layout of mine.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_background_search">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:tint="@color/color_primary_light"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/empty_search_result"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/search_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the current layout to search.xml and you said yourself that you do not have this file present.

setContentView is setting the layout that you will see when running the app in this instance.

Comment: But I don't understand what the layout of the search.xml should resemble. This is what I'm confused on.

Comment: should i just set it as R.layout.index if I want it the layout to be just as before?

Comment: What are you expecting that layout to be? The main layout when you open the app?

Comment: Yeah, i want the search to have a dropdown autocomplete function so Im thinking I just open the index file?